# JavaScript for-in loop with array -- get current key

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

say I have some kind of function `range` which creates an array from min to max, like `range(4,10)`. Say I want to loop through this array with a for-in loop like so:

```
for(i in range(4,10)) console.log(i);
```

If you try something like this out, you will notice that i starts from 0, not from 4. Is there a simple way (I guess without just adding the minimal ammount and without storing "range(4,10)" in a variable) to access the current value that is being looped through in the array? I believe in C# the syntax would be something like i.Key, does a similar property exist in the i variable? Or is there some kind of keyword that the value to the right of "in" is stored in within that scope that can be used for indexing?

Comment: Use `for..of` instead, `in` iterates over keys, not values (or, IMO, avoid `for` loops entirely, and use array methods instead)

Comment: @CertainPerformance whats "for...of"?

Comment: Just change your `in` to `of`. `in` iterates over enumerable and inherited property keys, `of` calls the `Symbol.iterator` of the object on the right

Comment: You can read the documentation of `for...of` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: @some you or  Certain should post that as an answer